# Are Adaptive Industrial Systems and Permanent Perennials Counter-Synergistic?

Tags: endless-space

Do these two System Improvements work together or against each other? That is to say, will the Perennials double my food surplus before it's converted to industry, or will my surplus food be converted to industry first, and then there is no surplus to be doubled?

Answer (score 4):

Anecdotally, when I buy `AIS` before `PP`, my industry goes up significantly, resulting in at least a thousand industry on reasonably balanced systems, leading me to believe that it doubles the surplus before it's converted, having had roughly 600-800 combined Food and Industry before buying `AIS`.